# Can we write a program consisting only of library calls

Tags: c, architecture, operating-system

my question is fairly simple, namely: Can we write a program consisting only of library calls and no system calls? My question comes from the context of C library calls and system calls.

Comment: If you use a library designed for a bare metal MCU, there will be no "system", so yeah of course it is possible. Why does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, whats the problem with this one. `printf` internally calls `write` but that is not known to us.

```
int main()
{
    printf("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: right, because it only internally uses system calls. So would I be right to say that a program would be more portable(between operating system) if I only used library calls?

Comment: yes you are right, internal implementation of `printf` can vary depends on systems, writing code using library calls make program portable. but the library call should be standard one.